# Login with Auth, but with extra fields beyond the login and password, using Cakephp 1.3

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, cakephp-1.3

I'm trying to do this kind of login, using the Auth component from Cakephp 1.3
but the component just use two fields (user and password) as you know.
so does anyone knows how a solution for get this login screen like the one in picture,
which is one field to Login, another to Password and the third field to choose
at what subsidiary from the firm (subsidiary 1, subsidiary 2,...) the user will be logged.
thanks in advanced.

[image: What kind of login i wanna do]

Comment: Exactly how does the subsidiary fit into your Authentication model? Can different subsidiaries have equal usernames? Or do you just want this as an additional security measure?

Answer (score 0):

for example you are using users controller and the subsidiary has no relation with users just tell us about it so that

we create `login.ctp` as

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'login'));
echo $this->Form->input('username');
echo $this->Form->input('password');
echo $this->Form->input('subsidiary', array('options' => array('subsidiary 1' => 'subsidiary1', 'subsidiary2' => 'subsidiary2'),'label'=>__('subsidiaries')
    ));
echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit'));
```

then in your user controller

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    if ($this->Auth->login()) {
    $subsidiary=$this->request->data;
    $_SESSION['Auth']['User']['subsidiary']=$subsidiary['User']['subsidiary'];
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
    } else {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
    }
}
```

now subsidiary is part of logged user data which is stored as session Auth User
this is one of solution maybe the other or even better solution can be used.